# Как получить массив полей объектов из массива объектов kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Имеется класс:

```
class FilterModel2 {
    var name: String? = null
    var count: String? = null
    var id: String? = null
}
```

это класс используется для обработки приходящего json с сервера:

```
 val listType1 = object : TypeToken<List<FilterModel2>>() {}.type
val profFilter = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<FilterModel2>>(responseFilter.getAsJsonArray("prof"), listType1)
```

и дальше после формирования массива объектов я разбрасываю поля элементов массива по другим массивам созданным четко под каждое поле:

```
for (filterModel2 in profFilter) {
    title1.add(filterModel2.name!!)
    count1.add(filterModel2.count!!)
    id1.add(filterModel2.id!!)
}
```

Вопрос - можно ли как-то усовершенствовать данный код? Можно ли как-то добавлять в массивы полей не в цикле, а другим способом, например так:

```
profFilter.map { it.name }
```

Это один из вариантов, но я не уверен что правильно его использую, поэтому решил спросить здесь :) Данный вариант при добавлении таким способом:

```
profTitles.addAll(profFilter.map { it.name } as ArrayList<String>)
```

выводит предупреждение: `Unchecked cast List to ArrayList...`

### UPDATE

Есть такой вариант, который вроде как принимается целевым массивом:

```
profTitles.addAll(ArrayList<String>(profFilter.map { it.name }))
```

но опять таки, хотелось бы услышать чужое мнение :)

Comment: Можно, только смысл? Это будет чуть медленнее, чем в цикле, потому что map аллоцирует и возвращает новый массив, а потом же в addAll этот новый массив копируется и выкидывается, и так 3 раза.А цикл ничего не аллоцирует(кроме массивов, куда записываются элементы) и проходится по profFilter только 1 раз. `map` имело бы смысл использовать если бы у вас были использовались неизменяемые коллекции, а у вас везде ArrayList'ы, тут можно и оставить императивный стиль. И зачем в последнем варианте использовать `as ArrayList<String>` ? Если profTitles это ArrayList, то addAll может и просто List принять.

Comment: @IR42, `profTitles` это `ArrayList<String>`, цель - возможная оптимизация) если мой текущий вариант, который я хочу улучшить, близок к идеалу, то смысла менять нет :)

Comment: достаточно `profTitles.addAll(profFilter.map { it.name })`, не нужно никаких as ArrayList или явно создавать ArrayList. Но в данном случае я бы оставил for

Comment: @IR42, а как вы считаете предложенный вариант будет лучше чем добавление через массив?